# Terminated by signal 4

Tags: swift

Already checked other question on this topic, and I can't seem to utilize it to resolve my issue, so I'm creating a new question in order to see if I can't gain some insight on this issue and help others who may run into this using the [Online Swift Playground](http://online.swiftplayground.run/).

Getting Terminated by signal 4 using the following code:

```
import Foundation
//enter equation here
var equation: String = "2 +( 3* 4)/ 2+22 ="
var equationWithoutWhitespace = equation.filter {!$0.isWhitespace}
//converts String equationWithoutWhitespace to array of Charcters e
let e = Array(equationWithoutWhitespace)

func add(_ firstVal: Int, _ secondVal: Int) -> Int {return Int(firstVal + secondVal)}
func sub(_ firstVal: Int, _ secondVal: Int) -> Int {return Int(firstVal - secondVal)}
func mul(_ firstVal: Int, _ secondVal: Int) -> Int {return Int(firstVal * secondVal)}
func div(_ firstVal: Int, _ secondVal: Int) -> Int {return Int(firstVal / secondVal)}
func power(_ firstVal: Double, _ secondVal: Double) -> Int {return Int(pow(firstVal,secondVal))}
func root(_ firstVal: Double, _ secondVal: Double) -> Int {return Int(pow(firstVal,1/secondVal))}
func checkParenthesis(_ equation: [Character]) -> (low: Int, high: Int){
    var low = 0
    var high = 0
    for (index,value) in equation.enumerated() {
        if(equation[index] == "("){
            low = index
        }
        else if(equation[index] == ")"){
            high = index
        }
    }
    return (low, high)
}
func doMath(firstVal: Character, op: Character, secondVal: Character) -> Int {
    var firstVar: Int! = Int("\(firstVal)")
    var secondVar: Int! = Int("\(secondVal)")
    switch op {
        case "+":
            return add(firstVar,secondVar)
        case "-":
            return sub(firstVar,secondVar)
        case "*":
            return mul(firstVar,secondVar)
        case "/":
            return div(firstVar,secondVar)
        case "x",
            "X":
            var firstV: Double! = Double("\(firstVar)")
            var secondV: Double! = Double("\(secondVar)")
            return power(firstV,secondV)
        case "r",
            "R":
            var firstV: Double! = Double("\(firstVar)")
            var secondV: Double! = Double("\(secondVar)")
            return root(firstV,secondV)
        default:
            print("error with operation detection")
            return 0
    }
}

//create new equation
var e2 = e
//get index of parenthesis & operation
var low = checkParenthesis(e2).low
var high = checkParenthesis(e2).high - 1
var op = low + 1

//if there were parenthesis, do this
if(low != 0 && high != 0){
    //remove parenthesis
    e2.remove(at: checkParenthesis(e2).low)
    e2.remove(at: checkParenthesis(e2).high)
    print(doMath(firstVal: e2[low],op: e2[op],secondVal: e2[high]))
}
```

Edit: this is a partial snippet of the complete project, it is essentially a text based calculator but it utilizes different rules than normal PEMDAS

Comment: Signal 4 is SIGILL, "Illegal instruction".  That usually means you have overwritten your code with data, and tried to execute that data.

Comment: Good to know.. I'll double check everything real quick. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking over it again today, and I found using `print(e2[low], e2[op], e2[high], low, op, high)`, I was able to check what values I was getting for my command, and realized I was 1 position off, because earlier I was compensating for removing the parenthesis, but later moved that function further down in the program. Because of this, `var high = checkParenthesis(e2).high - 1` was 1 value off and not giving me an integer, but instead a character. Changing the - 1  to - 2 fixed the issue and everything works as it should. Thanks to everyone for your help!